# Segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
   /* an array with 5 rows and 2 columns*/
   char* a[5][2];
   int y, p;

   for(y = 0; y < 5; y++)
   {
       for(p = 0; p < 2; p++)
       {
           scanf("%s", a[y][p]);
       }                      
   }       

   int i, j;

   /* output each array element's value */
   for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) 
   {            
      for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++ ) 
      {
         printf("a[%d][%d] = %s\n", i,j, a[i][j] );
      }
   }

   return 0;        
}
```

I've been getting a **Segmentation fault** as an output of this program after inserting 2 strings. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Step 1: What does your debugger say?

Comment: Hint: Your `a` character buffers are never initialized, so where is `scanf` putting that data? Probably at some random pointer location and blowing up your program.

Comment: Another hint: you need a line `a[y][p]=malloc(X);` just before `scanf("%s", a[y][p]);`, where `X` is the length of the string to be read plus 1.

Comment: When posting a question involving an error, you should tell us what you have already done to debug it and include any information that you can that will point us to the source of the fault.  Compiling with debug options enabled and executing under a debugger will do this; and would likely also let you fix the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Problem:*

You're declaring 10 uninitialized pointers here:

```
char* a[5][2];
```

And then trying to fill them with data:

```
scanf("%s", a[y][p]);
```

This is wrong. You need to allocate memory before copying data.

*Solution:*

I would do this in a more sexy way, but the quick solution would be:

```
#define MAX_LEN 100

char a[5][2][MAX_LEN];

/* ... */

scanf("%s", a[y][p][0]);
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",a[y][p][0]);` -> `scanf("%99s", a[y][p][0]);` to stop buffer overruns

Comment: @EdHeal, true. Also, not all compilers guarantee that variables are zeroed out: `memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));`

Comment: @Andrejs Cainikovs - No, it is not the truth. There are two cases - uninitialised variables with static storage (global variables and static local variables) are guaranteed to be zeroed, all uninitialized  automatic variables are guaranteed to be not initialised :).

Comment: @PeterJ I work as a developer for around 20 years now, but still initializing static variables on declaration (`static int x = 0;`). Thanks for the hint!

Comment: But remember  variables with static storage are initialised only ones - on the program startup. Sometimes is good to do it for humans.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint on helping troubleshoot. Hope this will help the future readers who are new to pointers.

A better way to troubleshoot a segmentation fault is to run it with a debugger like `gdb`.

e.g
Compile your program with gdb (You need gdb installed on your host)

```
gcc -ggdb Test.c -o Test
```

Then run it with gdb

```
gdb ./Test
```

In your case, you will see an output like this. It'll go to the `gdb` prompt. 
Then type `run` or `r`, it will run the program. Then it asks for an input. Type your input value. Then the segmentation fault occurs. Now you can see your backtrace by typing `backtrace` or `bt`. You can see which line causes your crash. You can see the code by `list`. You can go to any line by typeing `list <line>`. Go through a [GDB Guide](https://sourceware.org/gdb/) to find out more commands.

It tries to access a pointer, probably invalid that's why it crashes. Then find out why it's invalid. Probably you didn't initialize it or didn't allocate memory. So the easiest fix would be to declare it as an array (rather than a pointer array) like @Andrewjs mentioned in his answer.

```
Reading symbols from /tmp/Examples/Test...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/Examples/Test
for 1
for 2
10

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x005c5c3d in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=0x6d1420, format=0x804867e "%s", argptr=0xbfffe984 "\020\204\004\b", errp=0x0) at vfscanf.c:840
840                           *str++ = c;
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x005c5c3d in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=0x6d1420, format=0x804867e "%s", argptr=0xbfffe984 "\020\204\004\b", errp=0x0) at vfscanf.c:840
#1  0x005cebbb in __scanf (format=0x804867e "%s") at scanf.c:35
#2  0x0804850d in main () at Test.c:16   <-- Your program's last call
(gdb) list
835                       }
836     #else
837                       /* This is easy.  */
838                       if (!(flags & SUPPRESS))
839                         {
840                           *str++ = c;    <-- Crash point
841                           if ((flags & MALLOC)
842                               && (char *) str == *strptr + strsize)
843                             {
844                               /* Enlarge the buffer.  */
(gdb)
```

For advance debugging of applications [This may help](https://linux-audit.com/understand-and-configure-core-dumps-work-on-linux/)